# Passing string to jquery function

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {   
   $(".tweets").liveTweets({operator: "#google"});
            });
</script>
```

I like to make the #google as a variable, so that I can change the ticker symbol as needed. I tried to echo with php. But, it's breaking the live tweet jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to pass `'#google'` as a variable into the `liveTweets()` object? Or you want to use PHP to echo a variable into the `liveTweets()` object? Do you want to do this server-side or client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $operator = "#google";
?>

<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {   
   $(".tweets").liveTweets({operator: <?php echo json_encode($operator)?>});
            });
</script>
```

EDIT: Thank you for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125973/passing-string-to-jquery-function/16126081#comment23034302_16126081) @icktoofay.

He is right, we don't need to wrap output in double quotes, it does that for us. I've just updated it.

Comment: Don't build JavaScript with server side code. It's a bad design decision.

Comment: Of course it's bad practice. But If OP is trying to pass variable from server side on page load, that's one of the way to do this. Let's know what is your's?

Comment: `json_encode` already adds quotes; adding a pair around the call to `json_encode` will just generate invalid JavaScript like `""hello""`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am not building a super site. So used the jason_encode and worked great. FYI... I am trying to integrate this plugin in my financial website. http://codecanyon.net/item/live-tweets-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/154003  .. Now I need to see how to pass other variables.

Answer (score 0):

HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, and JS belongs in `.js` files. If you want to pass additional data from the server (PHP in this case) to JavaScript, you should use [`[data-*]` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Wherever you're defining your `.tweets` element, you should pass the value you want used for `operator` as a custom `data-*` attribute:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<?php
    $operator = '#google';
?>
<div class="tweets" data-operator="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($operator) ?>">
    ...contents...
</div>
```

In your separate JS file, you can then use the custom server variable when initializing the widget:

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('.tweets').each(function () {
    $(this).liveTweets({
        operator: $(this).data('operator')
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `data-*` attribute to contain the entire JSON object to initialize the widget:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<?php
    $liveTweets = array(
        'operator' => '#google'
    );
?>
<div class="tweets" data-live-tweets="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($liveTweets)) ?>">
    ...contents...
</div>
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('.tweets').each(function () {
    $(this).liveTweets($(this).data('liveTweets'));
});
```

Also, you could select elements based on the condition of having the appropriate `data-*` attribute:

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('[data-live-tweets]').each(function () {
    $(this).liveTweets($(this).data('liveTweets'));
});
```